# how to find the statistics of oracle service in remote machine?

Tags: java

Suppose an oracle service is running in remote machine and we want to find the number of  users using it, also the memory status of this service. how to do this using java.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there are native Java API's, but you can always connect over JDBC and fetch information from V$ views. V$SESSION is probably one you need to see connections, with memory it's a bit more complicated - check out documentation for V$PROCESS, V$PROCESS_MEMORY, V$SGA, V$SGAINFO, V$SGASTAT.